# get javadoc: error - Error writing highlight.js when generated jar file

Tags: android, jar, executable-jar

I'm working project which requires another project's .jar file. I'm using android studio 2.3.3. Following is code to generate .jar file

```
  task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/NAME.jar'}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'NAME.jar')}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

}

When i compile a project and call makejar it executes not successful and  i get bellow error:

```
Error:17:17:03.437 [ERROR] [system.err] javadoc: error - Error writing highlight.js: C:\Users\h.alvandi\Desktop\MTNIrancell_Android_RP\sul\build\docs\javadoc\highlight.pack.js: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
17:17:03.438 [ERROR] [system.err] 
17:17:03.439 [ERROR] [system.err] javadoc: error - Error writing highlight.js license: C:\Users\h.alvandi\Desktop\MTNIrancell_Android_RP\sul\build\docs\javadoc\highlight-LICENSE.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
17:17:03.439 [ERROR] [system.err] 
17:17:03.444 [ERROR] [system.err] javadoc: error - Error writing highlight.js style 'default': C:\Users\h.alvandi\Desktop\MTNIrancell_Android_RP\sul\build\docs\javadoc\highlight.css: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
17:17:03.445 [ERROR] [system.err] 
17:17:03.561 [ERROR] [system.err] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
17:17:03.783 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:17:03.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:17:03.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:17:03.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
17:17:03.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':sul:androidJavadoc'.
17:17:03.784 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Users\h.alvandi\Desktop\MTNIrancell_Android_RP\sul\build\tmp\androidJavadoc\javadoc.options'
17:17:03.785 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:17:03.785 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
17:17:03.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sul:androidJavadoc'.
17:17:03.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
17:17:03.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
17:17:03.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
17:17:03.786 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
17:17:03.787 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
17:17:03.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
17:17:03.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
17:17:03.789 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
17:17:03.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
17:17:03.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
17:17:03.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
17:17:03.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
17:17:03.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
17:17:03.791 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
17:17:03.794 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Users\h.alvandi\Desktop\MTNIrancell_Android_RP\sul\build\tmp\androidJavadoc\javadoc.options'
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.internal.JavadocGenerator.execute(JavadocGenerator.java:58)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.internal.JavadocGenerator.execute(JavadocGenerator.java:31)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.executeExternalJavadoc(Javadoc.java:156)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.Javadoc.generate(Javadoc.java:144)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
17:17:03.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 27 more
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\javadoc.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.tasks.javadoc.internal.JavadocGenerator.execute(JavadocGenerator.java:53)
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 43 more
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
17:17:03.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 31s
```

please help me !!!